# How to implement scrollable WebView inside bottom sheet?

Tags: android, flutter, webview, scroll, bottom-sheet

I have a `WebViewWidget` which is placed inside a modal bottom sheet. I expect

- the web view to be scrollable and
- the bottom sheet to be dismissable with a swipe gesture.

In other words, when I try to scroll down and the web view is already at its topmost position, the scroll must be passed to the bottom sheet (not unlike to how nested scrolling works in native Android).

By default, the web view is not scrollable. I know that `WebViewWidget` accepts `gestureRecognizers` where I can specify gestures I want to be handled by my web view. In particular, I can pass `EagerGestureRecognizer` (mentioned in all articles/questions related to this problem) which contains all gestures performed over the web view within that web view. It allows the web view to scroll but the bottom sheet can no longer be dismissed.

Is there a conventional solution to this issue?

Behavior with `gestureRecognizers: const {}`:

[image: no gestures]

Behavior with `gestureRecognizers: { Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer()) }`:

[image: with EagerGestureRecognizer]

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: DemoApp()));
}

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
          child: const Text('Show WebView'),
          onPressed: () => showWebView(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showWebView(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = WebViewController
        .fromPlatformCreationParams(const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams())
        ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276050/why-cant-i-scroll-custom-webview-in-flutter-modalbottomsheet'));

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: WebViewWidget(
          controller: controller,
          gestureRecognizers: { Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer()) },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```